# Tensorflow image classification - Probability prediction for input images

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have trained my model using Keras for image classification using tensorflow, and here's the code where my model is trying to predict an input image.

```
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
test_image = image.load_img('C:/Python/3.png', target_size = (64, 64))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
result = classifier.predict(test_image)
training_set.class_indices
if result[0][0] == 1.0:
    prediction = 'Anthracite'
if result[0][0] == 2.0:
    prediction = 'Bituminous'
if result[0][0] == 3.0:
    prediction = 'Lignite'
else:
    prediction = 'Peat'
```

Basically, i am working on an image classification problem where i am training my model by giving 4 types of coal, and my prediction is almost 80% perfect as i have trained my model with 25 epochs.

What i need is, the probability of each type of coal, let say, if my prediction says: It's lignite coal, it should also tell me the probability of accuracy that it's lignite, need help on this..

Comment: Hi, can you provide more details about how you create `classifier` ? I believe it is built on top of a Keras model that you have somewhere. If you have the model stored somewhere, you would just need to run `model.predict(test_image)`, and this will output the probabilities per-class.

Comment: @kuku Find the entire code here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1L7AH09irptcUzOnMHFmN79YRbg5_ho_D

but my model.predict(test_image) isn't giving probabilities, it's just storing the result and when i print the prediction variable, i just get which type of coal it is, not getting the probabilities, could you please help here..

Answer (score 0):

This modification will give you probabilities for each class given an image.

```
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
classifier.add(Flatten())
classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 4, activation = 'softmax'))
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

Here you need to train with `one hot encoding` and cross-entropy as the loss function.

Then during test time if you pass an image you will be getting an output vector (4 dimensions) each representing the probability of the image belonging to their respective classes.

Conversion to one-hot encoding: `keras.utils.to_categorical` function will help.

If you want to do fine-tuning with pre-trained models you can have a look at my [repository](https://github.com/tlokeshkumar/Fast-image-classification) where I used bottlenecks to accelerate finetuning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `classifier.predict_proba` api.